# using vtkSliderWidget with java in vtk

Tags: java, c++, vtk

when i use the vtkSliderWidget class on java i can't extract the value of the slider like that: sliderWidget.GetRepresentation().getvalue() is that wrong and is there any other method to do that, Best,AMAL

Answer (score 0):

Why not using `GetSliderRepresentation ()` of vtkSliderWidget class instead of `GetRepresentation()` of its mother class AbstractWidget.

Type returned `vtkSliderRepresentation` is more specific for your SliderWidget.

Can you try it ?